# Start matching after character in regex

Tags: python, regex

**What I want**

Suppose I have the following string:

```
"Abc def. 2. Ghi jkl. → 1. Mno 2. Pqrs 3. Tu 4 vx 5. yz..."
```

Now I want to write a regular expression in Python that matches and groups each list item after the character `→` such that each group would contain the list item number and the content for that list item, like this:

`('1', 'Mno')`

`('2', 'Pqrs')`

`('3', 'Tu 4 vx')`

`('5', 'yz..')`

In other words, after I encounter `→` I want to match patterns that look something like:

```
'([0-9]+)\.[" "]*(.*)'
```

I know that the obvious practical solution is to split the string and only search the section that comes after `→`, but I'm more interested in a theoretical, maybe-not-so-practical solution using only regular expression, in order to get a better understanding of regular expressions.

**What I've tried**

I have tried using look-behind like this:

```
'(?<=→)[" "]*([0-9]+)\.[" "]*(.*?)(?=[0-9]+\.|$)'
```

which finds the first match, but then things seem to get vastly more complex since it SEEMS as if I need to use another look-behind to match everything that's not the first occurrence. But since I don't know the length of the first list item, and Python only supports fixed-width look-behinds, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Maybe try to group matches like this: `'(?<=→)[" "]*(([0-9]+)\.[" "]*(.*?)(?=[0-9]+\.|$))+'`

Comment: It just matches the last list item, first both the number and the content, and then the number and content separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of the Python [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and make use of the `\G` anchor to get continuous matches. The `\G` anchor matches at the start of the string of at the end of the previous match.

Use 2 capturing groups to get the data and use regex.findall to return the values from the groups.

*Pattern*

```
(?:^[^→\r\n]*→|\G(?!^))[^\S\r\n]*(\d+)\.[^\S\r\n]*(.*?)[^\S\r\n]*(?=$|\d\.)
```

*Explanation*

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^[^→\r\n]*→` Match 0+ occurrences of any char except a newline or `→`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close group
- `[^\S\r\n]*` Match 0+ whitespaces except a newline
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits
- `\.?[^\S\r\n]*` Match an optional dot followed by 0+ whitespaces except a newline
- `(.*?)` Capture **group 2**, match any char 0+ times non greedy
- `[^\S\r\n]*` Match 0+ trailing whitespaces
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `$|\d\.` Assert end of string or match a digit and dot
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo in pcre](https://regex101.com/r/WSbI05/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##TY5LCsIwGIT3OcVYXCQqP/jaCFJcdSUIumusqI1arWlNo6i49gAe0YvU@oLuhm/gm0kvdpPodp5H@zQxFkat1ZmxdG6tMhp9GIe7vcAPnveHNFJPa0W4SY@7lUAIP5DjL@UyrAtJJUA1t9y7/epNhpKEw5hVmZ1l1hR6Z7BYIlQrQovgbSJsdzGh2ECTMNTJG48OJkObMDmig9MZXcLlSkSFKTWRtvxzmlaRDudxzH/fG/jPCMHy/AU)

*Code example*

```
import regex

pattern = r"(?:^[^→\r\n]*→|\G(?!^))[^\S\r\n]*(\d+)\.[^\S\r\n]*(.*?)[^\S\r\n]*(?=$|\d\.)"

test_str = "Abc def. 2. Ghi jkl. → 1. Mno 2. Pqrs 3. Tu 4 vx 5. yz..."

print(regex.findall(pattern, test_str))
```

*Output*

```
[('1', 'Mno'), ('2', 'Pqrs'), ('3', 'Tu 4 vx'), ('5', 'yz...')]
```

Comment: Brilliant solution and brilliantly explained! Much appreciated.